Download files depending on the contents of another downloaded one with Inno Setup and IDP (Multiple download processes with different timing)
I am trying to create web installer, downloading a file, read out its contents(file names), filling them as components then "continue" downloading only the components (the files), that were chosen by the user.
I need help with all the steps except configuring Inno Download Plugin to start downloading one file after wpWelcome and the other files after a custom select components page. So essentially, is it possible to configure IDP to download multiple files at different times during the same installer?
What I tried:
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  SelectComponentsLabel: TNewStaticText;
begin
  idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome); 
  idpAddFile('ftp://host.com/filesToDownload.txt', 
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\filesToDownload.txt'));
  CustomSelectComponentsPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectComponents,
    SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectComponents),SetupMessage(msgSelectComponentsDesc));
  .....//continue creating CustomSelectTasksPage 
ende;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Url, AppName: string;
  Lines: array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
 if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then // or maybe Check for custom page?
  begin
      idpClearFiles;
      ReadTextFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\filesToDownload.txt'), Lines);
      for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
      begin
        AppName := Lines[I];
        if not ListDownloaded then
         ComponentsList.AddCheckBox(AppName, '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
         if ComponentsList.Checked[I] then  // Check if checkbox is selected
         begin
           idpAddFile('ftp://host.com/'+AppName, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + AppName)); 
           idpDownloadAfter(CustomSelectComponentsPage.ID);    
        end;
      end;  
      ListDownloaded:= True; 
      idpFormActivate(nil); { This restarts the download }
      Result := False;
  end;
end;

As a result, I expect the idpForm to launch two times, one after the welcome screen to download the main text file and one more time after selecting components in the CustomSelectComponentsPage. But what happens is that all the files are downloaded one time after the welcome wizard page and the second configuration (idpDownloadAfter(CustomSelectComponentsPage.ID));

You add the checkbox, query its state and start the downloads at the same time. That cannot work.
You need to query checkbox state and start the downloads only after the user makes the selection. E.g. also from NextButtonClick, but only once the CurPageID = CustomSelectComponentsPage.ID. Something like this (untested):
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Url, AppName: string;
  Lines: array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    if not ListDownloaded then
    begin
      ReadTextFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\filesToDownload.txt'), Lines);
      for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
      begin
        AppName := Lines[I];
        ComponentsList.AddCheckBox(
          AppName, '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
      end;
      ListDownloaded := True; 
      idpDownloadAfter(CustomSelectComponentsPage.ID);    
    end;
  end
    else
  if CurPageID = CustomSelectComponentsPage.ID then
  begin
    idpClearFiles;
    for I := 0 to ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if ComponentsList.Checked[I] then  // Check if checkbox is selected
      begin
        idpAddFile(
          'ftp://example.com/' + AppName, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + AppName)); 
      end;
    end;  
    idpFormActivate(nil); // This restarts the download
    Result := False;
  end;
end;


Without testing I'm not sure, at what point should the idpDownloadAfter and idpFormActivate be called.

I also adjusted the ListDownloaded logic – I hope I've understood correctly your intention.


